# SQL Server Spatial Query: where condition behaving «oddly»

Tags: sql-server, spatial

I've realized this «silly» spatial query to find all the points that lie 5Km far form a center.
Source table holds +150K rows.

Here the query:

```
DECLARE @position geography = geography::Parse('POINT(9.123 45.123)')
DECLARE @circle geography = @position.STBuffer(5000) -- A circle of 5Km of radius

SELECT 
    g.Coordinate.STDistance(@position), g.Coordinate.Filter(@circle)
FROM 
    [DB_NAME].[SCHEMA].[TABLE] AS g WITH (nolock)
WHERE 
    g.Coordinate.Filter(@circle) = 1
```

I oddly observe that the `WHERE` condition doesn't work: in fact I retrieve even +600 points where the condition returns 0.

Any suggestions?

For the sake of clarity table schema was

```
[DB_NAME].[SCHEMA].[TABLE](Coordinate geography NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Presumably, `@Start_Position` is meant to be `@position`?

Comment: Also, [`Filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc627367.aspx): "This method is not deterministic and is not precise."

Comment: @Damien… the point is that Coordinate.Filter(@circle) returns 0 for some points (as I've checked) BUT the WHERE condition evaluates to TRUE.

Comment: "not deterministic" means that it *might* be returning 1 when it's being evaluated as part of the `WHERE` clause, even if, at other times, it returns 0.

Comment: I know the meaning… so you're saying that SQLServer evaluates twice the function: one for the filtering part and one for the projection…

Comment: It's a more reasonable explanation than "for some reason, sometimes, if this `bit` value has been obtained through XYZ method, the comparison of the bits `0` and `1` for equality will be considered true in the `WHERE` clause".

Comment: In ant case I've run the query multiple times and trying to varying the server workload but I sistematically get the same rows… A simple workaround is to wrap into an sub query… but honestly… I still miss the point

Comment: A better workaround would be (if you need it) `STIntersect`. Rather than go with the quick (occasionally wrong) result

Comment: Yes Demian but it outperforms slower and it's applicable just in this case (points in areas). Another note about the determinism: by what I've understood determinism impact false-positive. Negative matches are determined exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627367%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) states: «Returns 1 if a geography instance potentially intersects another geography instance. This method may produce a false-positive return, and the exact result may be plan-dependent. *Returns an accurate 0 value (**true negative return**) if there is no intersection of geography instances found*.»

So I mean that 0 is always ok, while 1 could be approximated (IMHO this behaviour is absolutely reasonable)

By the way @Damien observation lead me to simply work around:

```
DECLARE @position geography = geography::Parse('POINT(9.123 45.123)')
DECLARE @circle geography = @position.STBuffer(5000) -- A circle of 5Km of radius

SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 
       g.Coordinate.Filter(@circle) filter, g.Coordinate Coord
        FROM [DB_NAME].[SCHEMA].[TABLE] AS g WITH (nolock)
    WHERE 
        g.Coordinate.Filter(@circle) = 1
    ) t
    WHERE t.filter = 1
```

that recalls me the «[Double Check Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)» esoterism… but in that case It's clear the motivation.

One point that could be more investigated is about the return value conversion… Many years ago I stumbled upon on a similar issue where in a server farm an implicit conversion of a boolean tre to int led to -1 (0xFFFFFFFF) instead of 1 (0x00000001)… COM ages…